# Two variable quadratic equation over modulo prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers

Let $p$ be a prime and $c$ be a given integer.
Then, there exists an integer pair (a,b) such that $a^2 + b^2 \equiv c \mod p$ by the following link. 
http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lagarias/575chomework/2vpolycong1.pdf

There are many pairs that satisfies above equation, but we don't know the exact value of solutions in this link.
Is there a solution which satisfies $a^2 + b^2 \equiv c \mod p$ and $|a|,|b| \le \sqrt p$?

Answer (score 1):

The restriction $|a|, |b| \leq \sqrt{p}$ means that you're asking whether $a^2 + b^2 = c'$, where $c' < p$ and $c \equiv c' \bmod p$ (EDIT: not quite true; see comments). Solutions to this equation don't exist in general—one necessary but not sufficient condition for a solution, for example, is that $c' \not \equiv 3 \bmod 4$.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask one more question? um... what happened if $|a|\le \sqrt p$ or $|b| \le \sqrt p$ not $|a|,|b| \le \sqrt p$? By above link, there are $p+1$ or $p-1$ pairs, so all of pairs are larger than $p$?

Comment: Well, actually $c'$ could be as large as $(2-o(1)) p$, so possibly $a^2+b^2$ could be equal to $c'+p$.  But yes, this should be impossible when $c' \equiv p = 3 \pmod8$, for instance.